# scope para laravel de una relacion

Tags: laravel, controller, vistas, model, scope

Tengo una tabla de matriculas y una de alumno relacionadas, uno a muchos, y quiero hacer un scope en el modelo matricula de tal manera que me busque por el rut del alumno, de momento tengo un scope por fecha. como podria realizar ese scope? esto es o que tengo

```
class Matricula extends Model

protected $table = "matriculas";

protected $fillable = ['estado', 'monto', 'fecha', 'id_alumno'];

public function alumno()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Alumno::class,'id_alumno','id');
}

public function scopeSearch($query, $fecha)
{
    return $query->whereMonth('fecha', 'LIKE', "%$fecha%");
}
```

con ese scope solo puedo buscar por fechas, como puedo hacer uno para buscar por rut del alumno, si las tablas estan relacionadas?

Comment: ¿No sería más fácil obtener la matrícula a partir del alumno y hacer el scope en el modelo Alumno? Teniendo en cuenta que la relación está determinada por los Id, no por el Rut.

Comment: Como podria hacer eso?? tengo un scope en el modelo alumno pero lo uso solo en la vista de alumnos para buscar:  public function scopeSearch($query, $nombre)
    {
        return $query->where('nombre', 'LIKE', "%$nombre%");
    } como podria usarlo en la vista de matriculas??

Comment: No lo usarías en la vista, probablemente lo llames desde un controlador, repositorio o servicio.